# Galvanic isolation between three photovoltaic modules

Tags: circuit-analysis

Actually I am working on partially shading effect on photovoltaic (PV) module. In a PV array, many modules are connected in series, and voltage of every module sums with the next module. I want to find the shaded and unshadded module voltage by measuring the each module. I need galvanic isolation between each so that I can measure every module voltage. Is it possible or not? If possible, how it can be designed?

Comment: How about a schematic, and also drawing of the physical layout.

Comment: i can't put here schematic symbol or physical lay out. its just like addition of some PV panel in series.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series diode per module to semi-isolate them.

For heavy shading on one module that module will have lower voltage on the module side of the diode.

For light shading the overall panel voltage may still be high enough to allow the module to still deliver some power.  The voltage drop across the diode for the shaded module will usually be lower than for unshaded modules BUTas shading increases the opposite is true.

More accurate is to measure the voltage drop and so the current across a series resistance per module. This could be eg the feeder lead or a low resistance precision resistor. eg at say 10A a 10 milliohm sense resistor will drop 0.1V.

Often not an issue but note that for very long strings that give very high voltage, shading a cell that is not diode protected will lead to high reverse voltage across the shaded cell, which can produce cell catastrophic breakdown in low quality low isolation cells. Fire can happen in such cases.

Comment: thanks sir, i just required galvanic isolation between each module, is it enough by using connecting a series diode or not? is it possible by using a 1:1 ratio transformer or not?

Comment: @MohsinBilal Diodes will work in the manner I said. Transformers work only for AC so are if no use here. Note carefully what I said above re only minor shading NOT causing module voltages to fall much below bus voltage. Measuring current with a diode per module is liable to be the most reliable method.